# Store seperate sets of users in two tables or single table using ASP.NET MVC5 Identity framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am building a SaaS application using ASP.NET MVC 5, where I need to store two different types of users who will have different field information to be stored for each. There will be Subscibers and General Users, where every General user will belong to a Subscriber. So, every user will have a parent subscriber.

Should I have a single ASPNETUSERS table to store all the users (subscriber / general users) with custom columns stored for each within the same table? I believe there has to be a better practice to achieve this. Since this will be a SaaS application where we are storing user information across multiple entities in a single database, what kind of database design should we go for?

For reference, here is the database design I have for the moment -

id  [primary key of the user]
email 
password
sub_name  [subscriber name. will be populated only if the user is a subscriber]
sub_address [subscriber address, will be populated only if the user is a subscriber]
status [Stores if the user is active]
parent_id [Id of the parent. This will be populated only if the user is a General User]

Apart from the above, we will be registering the role of every user (Subscriber/General User)

Please advise. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a single table and create two classes in your code for the different types of users. The ASP tables with entity framework use table per hierarchy (given away by the discriminator column):

```
public class Subscriber : IdentityUser {

    public virtual List<GeneralUser> GeneralUsers {get; set;}
    //other properties
}
```

and then create your general users:

```
public class GeneralUser : IdentityUser {

    public virtual Subscriber Subs {get; set;}
    //other properties
}
```